# PHP validate IP address

Tags: php, networking, ip, ipv4, filter-var

```
<?php
$subdomain ='hello.cheapantivirus.me';
        $ns1 = 'ns01.000webhost.com';

$host = "@$ns1 $subdomain";
$ip = `/usr/bin/dig $host +short A`;

 echo $ip; // output is 31.170.161.67

 $ip3 = '84.8.161.5';

 if(filter_var($ip, FILTER_VALIDATE_IP, FILTER_FLAG_IPV4)) {
   echo "valid"; 
}
else {
  echo " not valid"; // the $ip is invalid
}


 if(filter_var($ip3, FILTER_VALIDATE_IP, FILTER_FLAG_IPV4)) {
   echo "valid"; // somehow this one is valid
}
else {
  echo " not valid";
}
?>
```

My question is why is $ip filter is being shown as invalid but $ip3 when I assign the IP manually the $ip3 filter is being shown as valid. Help me please?

Comment: Well, what does `$ip` contain?

Comment: `$ip` contain `31.170.161.67`. I just paste the full snipet above so anyone can just run it.

Comment: No it doesn't. `$ip == "31.170.161.67\n"` - the newline at the end is what's killing the filter. a simple `trim()` resolves this, as Pekka pointed out.

Comment: There is a trailing space at the end of the IP. I grab the output directly from dig actually.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The command line output may contain trailing spaces or line breaks.

Try

```
$ip = trim($ip);
```

before doing the validation.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. Somehow there is trailing space from dig output. It works. Thank you. I mark this as solved :)